# angular 7 not sending header on request

Tags: javascript, angular, http, http-headers, angular7

I'm trying to send content-type headers for the below post request to allow json request, but it throws me an error **Invalid CORS request**  with **OPTIONS** request method. It doesn't even send **POST** method.

Here, I cannot able to use `RequestOptions` which is depreciated.

PS: This is working fine when I send the request with postman. And, Backend code is handled with CORS request already.

From Backend java code, this the error I'm getting

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported
```

Where am I missing?

```
 postSubmit(){

        let data = { "name":"John", "age":30 };

         const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders ({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          });

            return this.http.post<any>(apiURL, data, {headers : httpHeaders})
            .pipe(catchError(error => this.handleError(error)))
          }
        }
```

Comment: This was happened on my past projects, to overcome this error use ` interceptor`.

Comment: Is 'content-type' (see the lowercase). Any way, if you're using HttpClient (not the old and deprecated http), by defect the data is sending in json format -you need'nt send httpHeader)

Comment: @Eliseo, cannot get you. can you elaborate? I'm using new httpclient which is in common/http

Comment: use simple this.http.post<any>(apiURL, data) or change your httpHeaders by const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders ({ **'content-type'**: 'application/json' });

Comment: Add CROS in your server side - i don't think the issue is on client - because the client pre-flight your request to http options but there is issue in your CROS try to fix it and try

Comment: yes the issue is fixed from backend side

Answer (score 2):

To define the content-type with the new  HttpHeaders class you need to

1. Just Import `import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http'`;
2. Create httpOptions object that will be passed to every HttpClient save method

   `import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
   const httpOptions = {
     headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
     })
   };`
3. Call the API `this.http.post<Datatype>(API url, Bady Parameter, httpOptions)`